# ZF2 return Objects in right Order from recursive Function

Tags: php, zend-framework2

Hey guys I need your help!

I am trying to accomplish a recursive function with Zend Framework 2 to retrieve all comments of an article inclusive their replies. The following picture should be clarify what I am trying to do:

[image]

In my case the first comment on the picture has a parent id = null and a comment id = 1 while the first reply has a parent id = 1 and a comment id = 3. The second comment has then the comment id = 2.

My recursive function returns all comments for the selected article, but not in the right order. So I get the comments like they are saved in the database: comment id = 1, then 2, 3 and so on but I need to get them like this: comment id = 1, then 3, then 4 and then 2. Here's my recursive function:

```
$select = $this->getSql()->select();
$select->where->equalTo("url", $url);
($recomment === null) ? $select->where->isNull("recomment") : $select->where->equalTo("recomment", $recomment);
$select->where->equalTo("status", "approved");
$select->order("cdate ASC");

$result = $this->selectWith($select);

foreach($result as $comment) {
    self::fetchListByUrl($comment->getUrl(), $comment->getId());
}

return $this->select($select);
```

The url param should refer to the article and the recomment to the parent id.

I hope there is someone who can help me to get the right order! :)

Comment: You have to rebuild a tree, not just list comment.

Comment: Well if I could get the right order, I think I can handle it the way I wanted to. If I var_dump the comments in the foreach loop it will be a tree in the correct order, but I can't find a way to save the data.